# Junit test case to insert data in DB

Tags: database, junit

In my project, I have to implement a JUnit testcase which will insert data in a DB table at the time of server start up.
Can anybody suggest how to implement it?

Comment: what application are you running? plain servlet based app or some mvc frame work?

Comment: @Prasanna Talakanti: Spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

I have listed few solutions here

1. Using spring init data base, add this to your spring context file, spring will execute the sql script as it boots up container

   ```
   <!--  Script with sql to insert statements -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database>
         <jdbc:script location="classpath:initDB.sql"/>
     </jdbc:initialize-database>
   ```
2. You can do that using code , This will tie your code to spring interfaces

   ```
    @Service
    public class InitializeDBService implements InitializingBean 
    {

      @Autowired
       JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

      @Override
       public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("your inserts");
       }
    }
   ```
3. You could use a servlet to do this

   ```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class InitDBServlet extends HttpServlet 
    {
     public void init() throws ServletException
     {
         //spawning the thread so that not to delay servlet start up
         new Thread(new InitDB()).start();
     }

     class InitDB implements Runnable
     {
     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
       //add your insert code here
     }
      }  
     }
   ```